# fade images in an endless loop

Tags: jquery, delay, infinite-loop

I have a single fade from image 1 to image 2 but what I would like is, to fade from image1 to image2 to image3 to image1.. and so on,  infinite in a `while(true)` kind of fashion, endlessly. How can I do this. Waht i have can be seen here: http://jsfiddle.net/bbqunfhu/23/ I have tried to achieve a second fade after a `delay(2000)` but even this somehow doesn't seem to work. Any assistance would be appreciated.

Comment: How about you just put another `setTimeout` inside the `fade` function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See http://jsfiddle.net/bbqunfhu/24/

You can't animate background-image so you need to include different div s with different backgorunds and iterate over them. This is what you can to iterate all divs with a certain class. What this does is; it gets all divs, finds the first visible div, fades it out, on `fadeOut`'s callback, it finds the next div (if the current div is the last div, it gets the first div by use of `%`) and fades that in. If you need to add more background images just add them to the page with the `bckgnd` class and you won't need to modify the code.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    setInterval(fadeDivs, 2000); //call it every 2 seconds

    function fadeDivs() {
    var visibleDiv = $('.bckgnd:visible:first'); //find first visible div
    visibleDiv.fadeOut(400, function () {  //fade out first visible div
       var allDivs = visibleDiv.parent().children(); //all divs to fade out / in
       var nextDivIndex = (allDivs.index(visibleDiv) + 1) % allDivs.length;  //index of next div that comes after visible div
       var nextdiv = allDivs.eq(nextDivIndex); //find the next visible div
       nextdiv.fadeIn(400); //fade it in
    });
    };

});
```

Answer (score 1):

Be careful when you use delay() in Javascript!
The execution will not get out of the function, resulting in general in a frizzy behavior.
Javascript offers a nice set of timing functions, one of which you are using (setTimeout).

- setTimeout(func, milliseconds) will call a function after some time has elapsed
- setInterval(func, milliseconds) will call a function every some time, until clearInterval is called

Here is an example to make three functions go in circle as you would like them to do:

```
function func1()
{
   // Do something like fading etc.
   setTimeout(func2, 1000);
}

function func2()
{
   // Do something like fading etc.
   setTimeout(func3, 1000);
}

function func3()
{
   // Do something like fading etc.
   setTimeout(func1, 1000);
}

// Call func1 somewhere here, maybe when page is loaded!
```

What will happen is: when func1 gets called, it executes some command (like the fading you need), then it will register a callback that will be fired after 1 second and return the control to the page. You will be able to interact normally with the page for that second. Once the second is elapsed, the timeout will be fired and the callback will be called. In this case, the callback points to func2, which will execute some command, register a callback to func3, return the control and so on.

Hope that helped!